# Proper way to display your own push message notification from non-running app in Android Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

Now that services are not running in the background, what is the proper way to generate and display your own notification from a push data payload? Is that possible anymore? I want the notification to have a different look and feel depending on the data payload. My GCM version of the app works fine, but my FCM version does not. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you define a little better what you mean by "my fcm version does not"?  What incorrect behavior are you seeing?

Comment: my apologies for the late response. What I meant was that I have a GCM version of my app that has been working fine. I know that you can specify the push as "high priority" which fixes the firebase version of my app, but, is there an alternative method for generating your own notification when a push is received while the app is either in the background or not running? this is on Android Oreo

Answer (score 1):

When you send the push data, are you including both a "data" payload and a "notification" payload?

Check the [documentation on receiving messages in Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).  If you send your FCM messages with only a "data" payload, then you can implement onMessageReceived() and that code will receive all notifications, both when the app is in the foreground and when it is in the background.

In your onMessageReceived() method, build your own notification in whatever style you want.  You can vary the style depending on the content of the "data" payload.  If you aren't familiar with building your own notifications, [here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

Comment: sorry been traveling and have been slow to respond. So I have gotten it all working by specifying these push messages as "high" priority. just a thought exercise here. lets say i do not update my app to FCM and continue to use GCM. Is there a way around Android Oreo's new background execution limits with a GCM client app? To pose a more generic question, can you process and display your own notification without having to start a service using GCM dependencies?